# responding to a jquery ajax post using servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

basically i have a username textbox that when a user input something it takes the value send it to server and server check the database that if the username is available, if so then the server needs to respond back to client a success so the client could understand username is available and turn the box border color to green.

my jquery ajax code, Client:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Registeration_Username_box').on('input', function() {
        postUsernameToServer();
    });

 function postUsernameToServer() {
      var formData = {
                'username': $('input[name=UserName]').val(),
              };
              // process the form
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                  url: '../dusernameavailable', // the url where we want to POST
                  data: formData, // our data object
                  dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                  encode: true,
                  contentType: "json",
                  success: function(response){
                        // we have the response
                        if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
                            alert("We received: " + response);

                        }else{
                            alert("Could not received data");    
                        }
                    },
                     error: function(e){
                       alert('Error: ' + e);
                     }
                }).done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                  });
    }

});
```

servlet server Code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String str = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    System.out.println(str);
    out.println(str);
}
```

just for testing purpose i have made the server to reply back the data received to client, so i could know we actually can send and receive data.

but here in my client side other than popping box with saying the data sent by server i am getting the error pop up box saying "Error: [Object Object]".

Comment: Is your servlet returning properly formatted utf-8 encoded json string? Or is returning something else? Like field, html, etc...

Comment: just tried "String str = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
     System.out.println(str);
     response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
     response.getWriter().write(str);" in my server, but no difference

Comment: IMO your servlet returned string is not json. Read this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

Comment: i tried this too "String json = new Gson().toJson(str);
     response.setContentType("application/json");
     response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
     response.getWriter().write(json);"

Comment: copy here that servlet returned string

Comment: i didn't understand you, you mean my server let received data from my client ajax,